# Do space satellites have physical intrusion sensors?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite

Do satellites sent into space have a physical **intrusion detection system** on board to prevent tampering?

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect the cost of such a system would exceed any likely benefit.

Comment: Not that I'd had heard of, but intrusion could probably detected offline (on ground) considering physical contact would lead to a momentary slight change of orientation. And "observation" satellites are precisely controlling (and monitoring) their orientation.

Comment: @DanielJour: How would a slight orientation change due to (e.g.) being boarded by space pirates be distinguished from a slight orientation change due to being hit by space debris or a meteoroid?

Comment: @Sean Not at all I suppose; but whether getting boarded or hit by something ... both is a possible total loss (especially when what his is of any noteworthy size ...)